# Restlet conditional routing to different resources

Tags: java, restlet

I have a `POST` request that I would like to assign to different `Resources` depending on the body content.

If the body contains a non empty *token*: `"token":"1q2w3e4r5t"` then I would like to rout the request to `TokenedResource,` otherwise rout to `NonTokenResource`.

I thought using Filter (`@beforeHandle`) for it, but the only indication the filter returns is `CONTINUE` or `STOP`...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to extend Restlet routing. The latter is responsible to determine which route matches for a particular request basing on a computed score.

In particular Routing involves two classes that you need to override: `Router` and `TemplateRoute`. The router one is responsible of the creation of the template route. If you want to provide a custom template route, you need to provide a custom router. Within the custom template route, you then implement your own algorithm regarding route score.

Here is the implementation of the custom router:

```
public class CustomRouter extends InternalRouter {
    public CustomRouter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFinderClass(CustomFinder.class);
    }

    protected TemplateRoute createRoute(String uriPattern,
                Restlet target, int matchingMode) {
        CustomTemplateRoute result = new CustomTemplateRoute(
                                    this, uriPattern, target);

        result.getTemplate().setMatchingMode(matchingMode);
        result.setMatchingQuery(getDefaultMatchingQuery());
        return result;
    }
}
```

What isn't so obvious to understand is why we need to specify a custom finder using the method `setFinderClass`. A finder in Restlet is responsible of instantiating for example a server resource for each request. The problem with the default implementation (the class `Finder`) is that you can't have access to the associated class (`targetClass`). If you need to know it (which seems to be the case), you must provide your own implementation. We'll focus on this later.

With this class, here is the way to attach your server resource within the application class:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new CustomRouter(getContext());

    router.attach("/test", TokenedResource.class);
    router.attach("/test", NonTokenResource.class);

    return router;
}
```

We must attach them on the same path.

Here is the implementation of the custom template route:

```
public class CustomTemplateRoute extends TemplateRoute {
    public CustomTemplateRoute(Restlet next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public CustomTemplateRoute(Router router,
                  String uriTemplate, Restlet next) {
        super(router, uriTemplate, next);
    }

    public CustomTemplateRoute(Router router,
                  Template template, Restlet next) {
        super(router, template, next);
    }

    @Override
    public float score(Request request, Response response) {
        float result = super.score(request, response);
        (...)
        return result;
    }
}
```

Within the method `score`, we will increase the score if we are in the case of a tokened request for the class `TokenedResource` and decrease otherwise. This allows to let Restlet select the right server resource for the right case.

Before going further, just let provide the content of the class CustomFinder:

```
public class CustomFinder extends Finder {
    private Class<? extends ServerResource> targetClass;

    public CustomFinder() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomFinder(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomFinder(Context context,
            Class<? extends ServerResource> targetClass) {
        super(context, targetClass);
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }
}
```

Here is a way to implement the custom processing to compute the score:

```
@Override
public float score(Request request, Response response) {
    float result = super.score(request, response);

    if (isTokenedServerResource()) {
        boolean containsToken = containsToken(request);
        if (containsToken) {
            return result + 0.1f;
        } else {
            return result - 0.1f;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The method `isTokenedServerResource` checks if the server resource associated with the route (if any) is the class `TokenedResource`. In this case, we have a look at the payload to see if it actually contains a token with the method `containsToken`.

Here is a sample content for method `isTokenedServerResource`:

```
private boolean isTokenedServerResource() {
    if (getNext() instanceof CustomFinder) {
        CustomFinder finder = (CustomFinder) getNext();
        if (MyServerResource1.class.isAssignableFrom(finder.getTargetClass())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is a sample content for method `containsToken`. It supposes that a JSON content is used and we use Jackson to parse it.

```
private boolean containsToken(Request request) {
    try {
        Representation repr = request.getEntity();
        String content = repr.getText();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> jsonContent = objectMapper.readValue(
                                  content, Map.class);

        StringRepresentation sRepr = new StringRepresentation(
                              content, repr.getMediaType());
        request.setEntity(sRepr);

        if (jsonContent.get("token") != null) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        (...)
    }
    return false;
}
```

An important thing to note is that we need to set again the request entity in the request (we use here a `StringRepresentation`) because by default the entity content can be read only once.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll get to it in a day or two.

Comment: You can have a look at this link https://github.com/templth/restlet-stackoverflow/tree/master/restlet/test-restlet-custom-routing for the code. Feel free to make me your comments!